# Python 2.7 - Raw_input and If and else

Tags: python-2.7

raw_input('What are you doing?     ')

a = 'nothing'
if type(a):
    print 'That seems boring'
else:
    print 'Nice'

The meaning of this code, is that if a person answers the raw_input with 'nothing'. It should print that seems boring. And if a person writes something else it should print ok.

I am new to programming so please help me :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, what you are looking for is:

```
a = raw_input("What are you doing?")
```

Notice that the answer to the prompt is saved in the variable 'a'.

```
if a == 'nothing':
    print 'That seems boring'
else:
    print 'Nice'
```

Pay attention to the indentation. Also, we use '==' for comparison and '=' for assigning values to a variable.

I suggest you learn basics of python from https://www.codecademy.com/

Answer (score 0):

I always like to make variables that show what they contain.
My version would look like this:

```
print "What are you doing?"
reply = raw_input()
if reply == "nothing":
    print "That seems boring"
else:
    print "Nice"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it like this, it will take input during run time in more oriented way

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

def user_input():

    print "What are you doing?" 
    # takes user input
    a = raw_input()
    # if user enter "Nothing" or "nothing"
    if (a == "Nothing") or (a == "nothing"):
        print "boring"
    # if he enters anything else
    else:
        print "nice"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    user_input()
```